# Extended Kendo Calender

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

how to bring kendocalender extended this way?
I use mvc4/razor

I have only this in my calendar.cshtml

```
<div class ="kendocalender">
  @(Html.Kendo().Calendar()
     .Name("Calendarname")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 180px;height:200px;font-size:13px" })
  )
</div>
```

This is my controller actionresult in calendarcontroller

```
public ActionResult Calendar()
{
    return View();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make static method in static class - extension method

```
public static MvcHtmlString KendoCalender<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string name, object htmlAttributes)
{
     string calenderControl = htmlHelper.Kendo().Editor()
                    .Name(name)
                    .HtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)
                    .ToHtmlString();

     return MvcHtmlString.Create(calenderControl);
}
```

include namespace in the View, and then you can call it from View by this code.

```
@Html.KendoCalender("CalenderName", new { style = "width: 180px;height:200px;font-size:13px" })
```

No need to add controller action method for that!!